# Display unique value

Tags: excel, unique, sumifs

Column A (CareID) has client's ID but shows multiple times, Column B shows the total amount)

I want to ask for the formula if the CareID in column A has Amount as $0, in column C show nothing or 0, if the Amount not 0 in column B, in column C shows the first value that appear in the column C, the duplicated careID shows as 0 or nothing.

Thanks

I tried SUMIFS or UNIQUE but didn't work

Comment: Pls. show a sample of data for input and desired output for easier understanding.

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you provide some sample data and expected output it is much easier to help you - best by using [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)  Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

```
=IF(SUM((A2=A$2:A2)*B$2:B2)=B2,B2,"")
```

**Result**

| Careid | Total |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 5 |
| 3 |  | 0 |
| 4 |  | 0 |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 10 | 10 |
| 1 | 11 |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 | 15 |  |
| 4 | 16 | 16 |